# Blur background content on pop up?

Tags: jquery, popup, shadowbox

SO this is more of a "is this possible" kind of question rather than "how can I fix my idiot errors?" sort of thing.

I want to use a shadowbox to display some content for a microsite, and I was thinking how neat it would be if instead of that transparent black overlay that always comes up, the content in the back would just get all blurred out.

Is that possible? I tried searching online but I didn't find anything relevant.

THanks in advance!

Comment: Well, I'm sure it's possible.  I know in jQuery UI they shade the background for a modal dialog.  I'm sure a similar effect could be achieved using a mosaic type of background image in place of a color to create a blur type of effect.  In case you haven't seen it:  http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal

Comment: There are other similar question on SO, but see this site as an example: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/14/item-blur-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is *possible*, but not widely supported across all browsers due to the use of transitions - older browsers aren't going to see this at all. The effect can be achieved with CSS3 and jQuery by following the guide found here http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/14/item-blur-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/.

Comment: Thats pretty neat, but not quite what I want to do. Ideally, what I'd like is when a link is clicked (say, an image thumbnail) the full size image would open up, and EVERYTHING behind it (full body I suppose) would blur. This would create a killer depth of field effect, and look super awesome. 

That said, if its not possible then its not possible. Boo. :D

Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

For a cross-browser solution, instead of the transparent black background you referenced, you could use a tiled background image that is a semi-transparent, blurred png created in photoshop using the "Blur" filter.

Comment: I see where you're going with that, but the problem there is that it wouldn't be a true defocusing of the actual page, but a faked version, ya know? I want all the content behind to blur, almost like its moved backwards physically and is no longer in focus. Know what I mean?